# Numeric Keypad, Touchpad, and Minimized Windows Not Working in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, mouse, touchpad

I'm having a problem with the above-mentioned components on my laptop. I really hope someone can help me out.

First of all, I wiped down my laptop today (first the screen with window cleaner and then the keyboard and mouse with alcohol) but it was turned off and I know better than to soak the thing.

After that, I started it up and everything seemed fine. I then opened Firefox and it installed the most recent update. After the update installed, I kept getting this pop-up for "Toggle Keys" or something. I kept pressing "no". Then I started having problems with the numeric keypad. It won't type in all the numbers, just some and a few act like the arrow keys. Not only that, but they're making random computer sounds. If I keep pressing a number like umpteen times it sometimes will then type it.

So of course, I searched Google, but then my touchpad buttons stopped working! I can still left-click on things using the pad, but the buttons are unresponsive. But not all the time. They'll start working and then stop abruptly.

And the last problem I'm having is that when I minimize windows, sometimes I can't get them to open again. It seems to happen when the touchpad goes out. I hover over them and the preview of the window just flashes. Now, as I was typing this out (using the Firefox browser) my little pop-ups for Grammarly are also flashing when the mouse malfunctions.

I messed with accessibility settings, typing, keyboard, and touchpad settings after reading some articles on how to fix similar issues, but nothing is working! I also tried updating the drivers, but my computer says they're all up to date.

Windows also updated yesterday and there was a feature update today that is currently being installed. After the computer restarts and if the issues are still not resolved I'll try doing a clean boot. But if anyone knows what's causing this and how to fix it I'd be forever grateful. Otherwise, I'm looking at a whole Windows Refresh, which would mean installing all my programs, fonts, add-ons, and all the other things that would be an absolute, time-consuming pain. My suspicion would be the most recent Firefox update did this because that's when I noticed it. But I have no idea what to do about that or how to roll-back to an earlier version. I've always used Firefox and have never had an issue like this so I really don't know.

Again, any help would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Would be helpful if you'd mention the device model and windows version.

But is it possible that a little alcohol slipped under the keys while cleaning ?
Although I don't think that's causing the problem but maybe.

"I also tried updating the drivers, but my computer says they're all up to date." - Did you try updating them from device manager, because that doesn't always work.

Its better that you download the touch-pad and keyboard driver directly from the manufacturers website.

Also, if you are not on windows 10 v1903 then visit this link:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
Click update now and check if your issue is resolved.

P.S- Next time you make a clean install make sure to make an image after installing all your applications and drivers and fonts , etc. It will save you a lot of time in the future.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. I guess I was so frazzled I forgot to include that info. I have a Sager NP6852 with an Intel Core i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80 GHz, 8 GB of RAM and it's running Windows 10 Home version 1903. So far, after the update, the mouse seems to be working along with the minimizing windows issue. But this is my first time really testing it. Fingers crossed it stays working. I did go through Device Manager to update and I'll try the official sites. However, my keyboard doesn't give me info on where to go. It just says it's a standard PS/2 Keyboard. I'm not sure where to go.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm so dumb :( I'm not really sure what you mean when you say "make an image"? Could you tell me? I'll try installing the drivers from the manufacturer's site and will let you know what happens. I just hope I can find out how to update the keyboard. It seems unlikely to me that any fluid got under the keys because I'm so careful. But who knows because I'm so dumb sometimes. Thank you so, so much for helping me out<3

Comment: The Sager NP6852 is based on the Clevo N850HK1, so it arrives in Clevo’s generic packaging. Two closed cell styrofoam pads keep the NP6852 secure, and there’s a separate compartment just for the 120W adapter. 

You’ll find a disc containing drivers and manuals, a quick guide booklet, a screw to install a 2.5" drive, and an extra thermal pad for the GPU’s VRAM.

Do you have any disc ?? Then try to install drivers from the disc, If you cant find them online.

Comment: I tried to find the drivers for you, but the sagernotebook website wont open on my pc

Comment: And about the image thing..check out this link:
https://www.pcworld.com/article/3011736/how-to-create-an-image-backup-in-windows-10-and-restore-it-if-need-be.html
Nobody is dumb !

Comment: Aww!!! Thank you<3 I feel dumb though lol I didn't get any discs with this one. The Sager site has an update for the driver, but it's older than the one I have. However, I did rollback the driver, maybe I'll see if I can get it to work. Thanks for the link and I'll get back to you :)